# Create word cloud for phrases (bigram,n-gram) in Python

Tags: python, word-cloud

I am using the `wordcloud` library to create word clouds but I need "phrase" clouds instead.
When I search for creating a word cloud for phrases I get a lot of hits but only for word clouds.
How do I create a word cloud for frequent phrases in a string?

this is what I've done so far (taken from stackoverflow):

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 
    ).generate(str(postData))
```

but I want a similar sort of implementation for bigrams / n-grams. please tell me how shall I approach this problem?

Comment: Did you try using `generate_from_frequencies()`? This lets you to use whatever you want as a ‘word’ - also I think you can pass a list (of ‘words’) to `generate(text)`, did you try that? Also I think you can specify a regex to split the text, you could influence the splitting of plaintext into ‘words’ which are sentences.